# Android How to send null value to server by Retrifit 2

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a query

```
@PUT("/share/{shareID}")
    fun updateShare(@Header("auth") auth: String,
                    @Path("shareID") shareID: String?,
                    @Body body: UpdateShare): Call<UpdateShareResponce>
```

UpdateShare class

```
class UpdateShare {

    @SerializedName("expireAt")
    var expireAt: Long? = 0
}
```

I have a case when field "expireAt" must be null, and i need to send it to server. But retrofit ignores fields with null. How i can do it ?

Comment: just send empty string

Comment: In Postman i white that " {
  "expireAt": null
}" , and it working

Comment: empty string don`t work because value must be null or number larger than cuurent time in msc. In my case it must be null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution.
Need to add to retrofit builder this

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(DIRECTORY_URL)
.client(client)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().**serializeNulls()**.create()))
.build()

Comment: god, why it can't serialize Nulls just by default, thx

Answer (score 0):

you can specify an int value as a null, for example, you can send -1 when the value should be null and On the server-side, when this value received save the null value instead of -1 in DB.

Comment: this is not an option :( value must be null

Comment: I think without have some changes on the Server Side, is not possible.

Comment: strange, I thought it was a typical task. But retrofit can not send null :(